# Error in jquery autocomplete function as 'a is null'

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

This function is called on onkeydown of textbox

```
function autoComplete(type, select) {
    $('#search_name').autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
        url: "/searches/autoComplete",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            term: $.trim(request.term)
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
            return {
                label: item.value,
                value: item.value,
                type : item.type,
                id   : item.id
            }
            }));
        }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        var url = ui.item.type + '/edit/' + ui.item.id;
        $(location).attr('href', url);
    }
    });

}
```

When checked in console gets an error as below

```
a is null

..."resolve"],fail:[b,"reject"],progress:[c,"notify"]},function(a,b){var c=b[0],e=b...
```

This error will comes only when no response `data` is returned, otherwise it is working fine.

How to avoid this error?

Comment: Wait. So you hit `success` but `data` is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are expecting a request to return data, but it's returning null, then that should not be treated as a success but as a failure. In your server code you should return 404 or something like that if you can't return the requested data.

**Edit:** From comments below, seems this was best solved using `header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");` in PHP.

I guess you could also just check in the JavaScript to avoid the error, but that isn't really a clean solution..

```
success: function( data ) {
    if(data) {
        response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
            return {
                label: item.value,
                value: item.value,
                type : item.type,
                id   : item.id
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think, if data is null(as here). Then ajax will not go into success callback...

Comment: In that case I guess data isn't actually null, but some blank object without the necessary properties you are trying to run a map on. Actually, the success callback does get called even if the returned data is null. How does your server side code look? As long as you return 200 OK status the success callback will get executed.

Comment: I am using php, In server side code just returned `echo null;` for no results.

Comment: Try using `header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");` and see what happens. I never use PHP but something like that should work.

Comment: Thanks.. This will cause jQuery to run its error handler and in turn fail the Ajax deferred. Should I need to return 404 or javscript check? Because it just an autocomplete dropdown list will dropdown on response, otherwise don't...

Comment: It's always better to return correct status than let the JavaScript success handler determine if a request was *really* successful. So I would definitely return the correct status (in this case 404).